# How to scroll to bottom of div generated by ng-repeat Angular JS using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Following is my template code:

```
<div class="chatbox" id="mailBody" >
    <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="mail in mails">

      <div class="m-b-none" ng-if="mail.inboxMessageType == 1">
        <a href class="pull-left thumb-sm avatar" ng-if="senderLength>=10"><img src="img/a2.jpg" alt="..."></a>
        <a href class="pull-left thumb-sm avatar" ng-if="senderLength<10"><img src="img/business2.png" alt="..."></a>
        <div class="m-l-xxl">
          <div class="pos-rlt wrapper b b-light r r-2x">
            <span class="arrow left pull-up"></span>
            <p class="m-b-none mailbody">{{mail.body}}</p>
            <p><span class="label bg-info dk m-l-sm taglist" ng-repeat="tag in mail.taglist" ng-if="mail.taglist">{{tag.name}}</span></p>
          </div>
          <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-ok text-success"></i>{{ mail.date}}</small>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to scroll to the bottom of this chatbox when it loads. i did it through JQuery. Here is the code :

```
     $('#mailBody').stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#mailBody")[0].scrollHeight}, 2000);
```

It is scrolling down but stopping in the middle. Is there any event which I can attach on full load of the div or how to do it?

Chatbox CSS :

```
.chatbox {
 height: 327px;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Can anybody guide me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using Angular Directive.

```
   angular.module('app')
  .directive('myScrollDirective', function() {
   return function(scope, $element, attrs) {

   if (scope.$last){
  //window.alert("im the last!");
   window.setInterval(function() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('smsBody');
      elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
     foo();
    }, 1000);
  var foo = function () {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    };
}
};
 });
```

And on the page I just added this directive.

```
div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="mail in mails" my-scroll-directive>
```

That's it. Thanks to Stackoverflow Community!

Answer (score 0):

Please place your post code in post link method if the directive.

Comment: Im doing it through JQuery and I have already posted the code which I m using.
 $('#mailBody').stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#mailBody")[0].scrollHeight}, 2000);